# Как произвести релевантный поиск?

Tags: postgresql, поисковые-системы

У меня есть таблица:

news и 4 поля
id
text
time
author

Как мне выполнить поиск в новостях и отсортировать данные по релевантности, то есть вывести новости, где указанная фраза наиболее точно встречается?

```
SELECT id FROM news WHERE  MATCH (text) AGAINST ('Российские ВКС в Сирии') ORDER BY rel
```

В идеале конечно и возвратить участок текста, где было найдено +- 100-200 символов.

Comment: Неточные совпадения этот запрос и не поймает, посему релевантность для него не имеет смысла, она для всех строк будет одинаковой.

Comment: Так и хочу понять как делать запрос с релевантностью. На примере этой таблицы.

Comment: Тогда запрос лучше выкинуть из вопроса, с ним вопрос становится бессмысленным. Хотите приложить структуру таблицы -- лучше её и приложите. А касательно ответа -- в постгресе [целый раздел в документации посвящён полнотекстовому поиску](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch.html).

Comment: базы данных не предназначены для нечеткого поиска (несмотря на то, что там можно это дело реализовать)

Comment: @etki
А какие средства тогда лучше использовать?
Сейчас у меня есть данные в таблице БД postgresql.

Comment: @D-side
Полнотекстовый поиск не работает почему то. Возможно его исключили из новых версий БД.

Comment: @manking или возможно нужно предварительно создать индекс для полнотекстового поиска, и создаётся он обычно долго

Comment: @manking скорее вы не смогли его настроить, т. к., опять же, не прочитали документацию. В селекторе версий для этого раздела есть десятый, самый что ни на есть свежий постгрес. Но etki прав, есть решения получше, поисковые серверы. Например, ElasticSearch, его используют здесь, на SO. Есть также Sphinx, Solr... поищите.

Comment: А какой самый простой и малозатратный путь?
Интересует такой какой присутствует в mysql по умолчанию. Получается в postgresql таких простых путей нет?

Comment: Полнотекстовый поиск это всегда сложная тема. Если какие-то простые пути вдруг и есть, то потом окажется, что они работают криво

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
SELECT id 
FROM news, to_tsquery('Российские & ВКС & Сирии') query
WHERE to_tsvector(text) @@ query
ORDER BY ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(text), query) DESC
```

Подробнее тут https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html

Comment: Он не всё ищет. 
Если например есть нижнее подчёркивание, то он не находит. В html не находит названия классов и.т.д.

например он разбивает на слова. Хотя не нужно. 
SELECT to_tsquery('fifa_history__header') query

Выводит :
fifa' & 'histori' & 'header'

Comment: Даже не знаю. Никогда не думал о том, что кому-то понадобится искать подчёркивания:)

Comment: @manking эти ваши требования противоречат исходному вопросу. Вы определитесь, или неточный поиск с релевантностью, или точный без релевантности

Comment: В моем понимании нижнее подчеркивание это часть слова, а вот пробелы нет.

Comment: Просто он не находит фразу которая в тексте точно есть. 
Например. 
custom-hash=

Получается надо искать на точное совпадение, а уже если не найдено, то поиск по релевантности?

Comment: А ну в принципе я могу наверное удалять подчеркивания из поисковой фразы. Но будет ли это правильным с точки зрения поиска?